# How to parse, and render, json use in Flask template

Tags: python, json, templates, flask

Here's my Flask app code:

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify
import requests
from app.test_blueprint import app


@app.route('/')
def index():

    url = 'http://api.address'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

And a snippet from the `index.html` template:

```
 <div class="title">
 {% for item in data %}
     <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
 {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

parsing the url address to send an HTTP GET request which has been sprayed on the screen , and then it will give . In JSON to create customized to show to object. I got the JSON data output by inserting a data item in the template , but it does not appear on the screen. Is any part of this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `data` is a JSON object not an array, the response is being translated into a Python dictionary.  Iterating over a dictionary returns the *keys*, not the values.  This means that you try to access the attribute `item` on a string (and strings in Python don't have an "item" attribute).  There are several ways you could fix this:

```
{# 1. Use the key to access the value from data #}
{% for key in data %}
  {{ data[key].item }}
{% endfor %}

{# 2. Explicitly enumerate the values #}
{% for value in data.values() %}
  {{ value.item }}
{% endfor %}

{# 3. Enumerate key-value pairs #}
{% for key, value in data.items() %}
  {{ value.item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is not looking right. the output of a `json.dumps' is a `str` object. You will get an error like so: `undefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: In this case, `data` is the result of a `json.loads` which is a Python list or dictionary, and in this case, a dictionary.

Comment: @downvoter - care to explain what is wrong so it can be corrected?

Comment: Error... doesnt work, sorry on '14... didnt pay attention